# Conditionally include css files with meteor

Tags: meteor

I am making a "multipage" app with meteor and would like to use different css files per page. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess `<style>` might work

Comment: Downvoters: please explain why you downvoted this question!

Comment: I actually upvoted this its a good question, Meteor doesn't use conventional style pages, rather in a router.

Comment: I upvoted too. I'm here to look for solutions to include different js scripts for multipage app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meteor doesn't allow (currently) helpers inside the  tag.

Rapid way: wrap all your content inside a div with an #id an then use stylus to wrap all the css rules ander that tag:

```
#myPagewrap1
  #row
    some: rule

#myPagewrap1
  #row
    some: rule
```

Long way: attach some dynamic css call to the .created method of your template.

```
Template.myPage.created = function(){
  loadStyle("pathtostyle.css");
}
```

And your loadStyle function could be something like this: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: Thanks! Went with this: Template.customPage.created = function () {
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css"/>');
};

Comment: Make sure to add a condition to check if the stylesheet has already been added to the head, otherwise you'll have a bunch of duplicates.

Comment: this is not working. Meteor automatically pushes all the css files to the client.

Comment: @piedpiper put your CSS files in /public.